# Хранение параметров доски объявлений

Tags: php, mysql, select

Хочу реализовать для своей доски объявлений при добавлении объявления ввод дополнительных параметров на основании выбранной рубрики.

Примеры тут:

- http://olx.ua/post-new-ad/
- https://www.avito.ru/additem

(при выборе рубрики выскакивают дополнительные параметры)

Список параметров и их возможные значения я сохранил в отдельном массиве.
Нерешенным остается вопрос как правильно записать эти параметры в базу *Mysql*, чтобы по ним можно было еще и осуществить выборку.

Первое что пришло на ум, это создать в базе столбец `param`, записать туда все параметры в *JSON-виде*, а при открытии объявления распарсить эту запись. Но как же сделать выборку? `LIKE` или `FIND_IN_SET` использовать? Не знаю насколько это правильно. Тем более если объявлений немало со временем будет.

Может есть какие нибудь идеи, подскажите.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON или любой другой способ сериализации отпадает если нужен поиск по любому из значений.

Модель Атрибут-Значение вам уже предложили, а я предложу самый простой в реализации вариант: таблицу с полным набором всех атрибутов и полем-типом.

Ненужные поля просто будут оставаться пустыми (с null или с дефолтовыми значениями). Ничего страшного в такой "разреженной" таблице нет. Зато запросы на выборку будут простыми и быстрыми.

Атрибут-Значение хорош когда список полей растёт и вообще потенциально бесконечен. А в вашем случе, мне кажется, перечень утвердится довольно быстро и создавать их динамически незачем.

Comment: Подскажите какой тип данных выбрать для значений чтобы неиспользованные значения не занимали память? Для цифровых значений сначала выбрал int, но потом смотрю что если поле не использовано, там 0 хранится, который по ходу 4 байта занимает. Пока выбрал varchar.

Comment: Тип надо брать подходящий для значений: для денег numeric, для кол-ва int, для даты date… Сколько места это будет занимать это дело десятое или стопятидесятое. Место дёшево! Но для общей информации:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage — зависит от выбранного движка.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, который просится первым это создать отдельную таблицу в которой хранить отдельно для каждого параметра ID рубрики, ключ, значение.

И делать выборку или JOIN по ID рубрики.Можно сразу отбирать только параметры по ключу или значению.

Если нужны подробности спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, вам нужно хранить информацию в виде «ключ-значение».

один из множества возможных вариантов, как это можно реализовать:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf119b/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table kluchi (id int not null auto_increment primary key, opisanie varchar(100));
create table znachenija (id int not null auto_increment primary key,
                         klient int,
                         kluch int references kluchi(id),
                         znachenie varchar(100));
insert into kluchi(opisanie) values("ключ1"), ("ключ2");
insert into znachenija(klient, kluch, znachenie) values
  (1, 1, "значение1"),
  (1, 2, "значение2"),
  (2, 1, "значение3"),
  (2, 2, "значение4");
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from kluchi
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf119b/1/0)**:

```
| id | opisanie |
|----|----------|
|  1 |    ключ1 |
|  2 |    ключ2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from znachenija
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf119b/1/1)**:

```
| id | klient | kluch | znachenie |
|----|--------|-------|-----------|
|  1 |      1 |     1 | значение1 |
|  2 |      1 |     2 | значение2 |
|  3 |      2 |     1 | значение3 |
|  4 |      2 |     2 | значение4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал посмотреть как для реализована База Данных для Drupal 7.
Там каждое поле имеет отдельную таблицу и эти поля очень удобно связывать с материалом(а в вашем случае - с рубрикой).